# How to Summerize docments in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 10 million documents in an index , that can be actually summerized into just a few thousand documents , but I need to know how.

Sample fields:

```
remote ip , endpoint , number of requests
```

based on similar `remote ip` and `endpoint` , the field `number of requests` can be aggregated , such that I have a single line/document , for example , for 1000 requests , instead of having 1000 documents with 1 request , I can have just one document with 1000 rquests:

```
<remote ip> , <endpoint> , 1000
```

How can I aggregate the data such that I reduce the the number of documents and index size.

Note: the raw data is not available to be re-ingested in aggregated form.

Comment: You're probably looking for the [rollup API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rollup-apis.html).

Comment: @ChrisHeald but that is an Xpack paid feature? I am using the free version

Comment: Rollups are included in the free/basic xpack license.